# Создание дополнительного поля и проверка правильности ввода данных

Tags: php

Как сделать дополнительное поле в комментариях, например, в левой части будет вопрос: "Сколько будет 1+1?" и чуть правей поле для ввода ответа, если пользователь отвечает 1, то комментарий после нажатия на стандартную кнопку "отправить комментарий" не добавляется, если же 2, то комментарий добавляется?

Сам процесс я понимаю. Создаем поле ввода данных:

```
Сколько будет 1+1? <input type="text" name="name">
```

Затем пишем условие:

```
<? 
    if( $_POST['name'] == '2' ){
         echo '<input class="floatl" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Submit Comment" />
         <input type="hidden" name="comment_post_ID" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />';
    }
    else{
        echo '<h1>Не правильно!</h1>';
    }
?>
```

В данном случае должна появляться кнопка для добавления комментария, если цифра введена верно, но что-то здесь неправильно, т.к. кнопка не появляется.

Comment: А вы точно post'ом отсылаете данные?

Comment: ling, get'ом тоже пробовал...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

эм... тут проблема только в том, что дополнительное поле появляется уже после загрузки формы и "POST"ом не валидируется. Сделайте тоже самое поле, только отображайте его в нужное время, меняя, скажем, css-свойство display. Тогда всё будет хорошо.

Answer (score 0):

Я предполагаю что кнопка у Вас появляется, но она имеет стиль float1. Приведите код css для float1. Возможно в нем и есть весь подвох - вы просто не видите ее, но она есть на форме.

P.S.:С другой стороны, как Вы полагаете, удобно ли пользователю два раза нажимать на добавить комментарий? Нельзя ли осуществить проверку и сразу же записать в базу комментарий?)

Comment: Если убрать проверку и вопрос, то все нормально отображается.
>Нельзя ли осуществить проверку и сразу же записать в базу комментарий?
Я и хотел так сделать, но не знаю как...

Answer (score 0):

> ling, get'ом тоже пробовал...

Get'ом точно не сработает. Плюс, `value="<?php echo $id; ?>"` замените на `value="'.$id.'"`, а то получается, что у вас php блок закрывается слишком рано.

Comment: ling, не помогло.

Comment: Тогда `print_r($_POST);`. Если пишет `Array( )`, значит форма не отправлена.

Answer (score 0):

а почему бы вам не сделать это на JavaScript и пока не будет введено верное значение кнопку submit держать неактивной для кликов.. там строк 20 кода будет максимум.. это избавить и вас и пользователей от дублирования особенно если после неверно введеного значения вы не подставите введенные пользователем данные на свои места...